# Nivo Lightbox layout: not centered or resizing image properly

Tags: css, responsive-design, lightbox, nivo-slider

http://www.imageworkshop.com/2014/03/03/miranda-revisited-portrait-of-anne-louise-lambert-at-hanging-rock/

When an image is clicked it launches in the Nivo lightbox. This was working perfectly until recently. an image will be centered and resize responsively to remain centered. (you can see an example of it working correctly here: http://www.sandbox.sharonblance.com/project/melbourne-town/)

Suddenly this doesn't seem to be working properly anymore. I have recently upgraded from v1.0 to v1.2 of the .js library for the lightbox, however, rolling this back does not fix the issue - so it must be related to some other CSS or theme change somewhere that is affecting the lightbox?

I am also seeing scrollbars showing up when the screen is resized small which is not correct.

I noticed that hiding the following rule seemed to influence the left/right alignment, however I cannot find a way to fix all the issues I am seeing:

```
.nivo-lightbox-effect-slideLeft.nivo-lightbox-open .nivo-lightbox-wrap, 
.nivo-lightbox-effect-slideRight.nivo-lightbox-open .nivo-lightbox-wrap {
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

Comment: Weirdly I've found that it was because I'd disabled Jetpack Photon that it wasn't working. re-enabling this has fixed the issue - however, I'm confused as to why PHOTON would make ANY difference here?

Answer (score 0):

from the nivo-lightbox.css
I added/changed (gave it a fixed width) it to this

```
.nivo-lightbox-content {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width: 800px;
height: 100%;
}
```